# JS Module Security

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, module

Recently finished a module of which is supposed to track the inventory of a store. Upon completion, the project was returned to me because the security of the internal information is lacking, e.g. test cases allow modification of the inventory and such.
Module:

```
'use strict';

let obj = {};

let list = [];

let sortedList = [];

obj.addItem = function(name, price) {
    let item = {name:name, price:price};
    list.push(item);
};

obj.items = function(){
    let sortList = list;

    let completeSort = sortList.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price;
    });

    completeSort.forEach(function (itemObject) {
        sortedList.push(itemObject);
    });

    return completeSort;
};

obj.getMostExpensive = function() {
    let sortList = list;

    let completeSort = sortList.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price;
    });

    completeSort.forEach(function (itemObject) {
        sortedList.push(itemObject);
    });

    let hCostIndex = (sortedList.length) - 1;

    let mostExpensive = sortedList[hCostIndex];

    return mostExpensive;
};

obj.getLeastExpensive = function() {
    let sortList = list;

    let completeSort = sortList.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price;
    });

    completeSort.forEach(function (itemObject) {
        sortedList.push(itemObject);
    });

    let lCostIndex = sortedList[0];

    let leastExpensive = lCostIndex;

    return leastExpensive;
};

obj.removeItem = function(name) {
    let index = 0;
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        if(item.name == name){
            index = list.indexOf(item);
            if (index >= 0){
                list.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });
};

obj.getItemByName = function(name) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(list[i].name == name){
            return list[i];
        }
    }
};

obj.getItemByPrice = function(price) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(list[i].price == price){
            return list[i];
        }
    }
};

module.exports = obj;
```

The problem mainly is that the items function and my other functions that return an inventory item can be used to modify the inventory information, and I don't know how to prevent that from happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT--
I believe I've fixed it, given the answers I've been provided. Should this change to the item function fix the issue?

```
obj.items = function(){
    let sortedList = [];

    let completeSort = list.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price;
    });

    completeSort.forEach(function (itemObject) {
        sortedList.push(itemObject);
    });

    return sortedList;
};
```

Comment: You could of course only return copies of the items (so that the original items can't be modified), but really how can this possibly be a *security* issue? Alternatively, make each `item` [immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

Comment: Just curious, but wth is the deal with `sortedList`?

Comment: As i said, i have no idea how to fix this so the sortedList was an attempt at the copying thing; i don't believe i've done that correctly at all however

Comment: Ah, copying the list itself will be necessary as well *when returning it from the `items` method* (I was thinking mostly of copying the individual objects that are returned by the `get…` methods). But for that, you a) need to initialise a new `sortedList` on every `items` call and b) actually return the copied `sortedList` (instead of the original `completeSort` - which is `=== sortList`), and c) don't need to append anything to `sortedList` when calling `getMost/LeastExpensive`.

Comment: I've edited the code above, could you provide some more insight please?

Comment: That should do. Of course, to make a copy of an array I would recommend `slice` or `map`, not a  `forEach`+`push` combination, and you probably should use `Object.freeze` on every `item` that you add. Then ask your reviewer what kind of threat scenarios you are supposed to secure the code against.